# passing value to url in wordpress plugin does not work

Tags: php, wordpress

I am writing a wordpress plugin and I want to pass some values to url when I click on a edit link in my plugin.

The menu is a separate wordpress main dashboard menu and my link is :

```
<a href="?page=easy-flexible-testimonial/testimonial.php?id=1">Edit</a>
```

Now the problem is whenever I am clicking on the link its displaying a message:

```
"You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page."
```

Comment: you can not use `?` twice. That is the query string, and after first `?` you need to use `&` for key/value pairs. For example: `example.com/?first_param=value&foo=bar&something=anything` and so on

Comment: oh yes you are right, I just could not keep that in  mind!!!! Thank you!